# Getting title metadata given website url in python

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup, facebook-opengraph

I'm looking to achieve this using beautiful soup. Currently I'm able to pull og:title from a webpage. What if no og:title is given? Is there a way to identify the title and display that?

Comment: use `print()` to see what you have in HTML and maybe you find something similar.

Comment: can you be more specific? Are you scraping a specific site? Or could it be any site?

Comment: Given any site, regardless of whether og:title is given or not, how can I take some sort of title/description and insert it into my Django model?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will clear your doubt, you can fetch every meta property you want with similar code like the below one.

```
title = soup.find("meta",  property="og:title")
url = soup.find("meta",  property="og:url")
```